# Please explain subscript t and the statistical meaning of this table

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to get a thorough understanding of this thesis' statistics. Please see the photo[image]

Can you explain what is the meaning of subscript "t + 1" and "t-1" for CFO please?

Also, what do the numbers in the Pearson (Spearman) correlation table mean exactly and how can I interpret them?

Comment: The $t+1$ and $t$ and $t-1$ subscript are likely meant to indicate the value of that variable at different moments in time. The correlation numbers in the table are correlation coefficients. You can look up the definition of the Pearson correlation on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical corporate finance or accounting research data. In [this case](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2696498) it's accounting, and they use Compustat db. Index $t$ refers to the period of the financials release, usually quarterly.

Pearson correlation is a usual correlation between $CFO_{t-1}$ and $CFO_{t}$ where you control the firm $i$. In this case it's a correlation between CFO on the release date and prior quarter of the same firm. In Panel B it's about 68% correlation between current quarter cashflow from operations and the previous quarter.